# How do I include an npm plugin in gulp build when using UnderStrap WordPress theme?

Tags: wordpress, npm, gulp

From the homepage of [understrap](https://understrap.com/)

> Comes with npm support to manage all the dependencies. Just one command in your terminal is needed to update all assets.

This is exactly what I'm trying to do. Install a plugin from npm, in my case lity. I've run `npm install lity --save` on the theme directory. But, I'm not at a loss of how to correctly get the js file into the gulp build precess.

From the quote on the homepage, I assume there's a way to do this without editing the gulp.js file. But the [understrap docs](https://understrap.github.io/) are a work in progress. So I'm struggling.

Comment: That is my personal opinion but do not use understrap as this theme, especially build process, assets management contains many bad practices and its simply outdated.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your pov. It's too late to change for the current project, but I'm thinking of suggesting the client uses sage in the future. Their asset management in version 8 worked well, I'm yet to try 9. Do you have any other recommendations for a good bootstrap starter theme, that's frontend dev friendly?

Comment: I am bit biased here as I created my own starter theme but Sage is always a good choice (but can be a bit complex)

Comment: Sage might be most suitable to pitch to them because of it's maturity, but I'll check your theme out on one of my own projects. Cheers :)

Answer (score 0):

I am speaking out of experience.  If you have intentional plans on installing addition npm modules for your project, you are better off (**at the moment**) looking at an alternative theme package.  Until the UnderStrap team provides a clear documentation process on how to extend their npm package system, it appears that we use what they got.  I personally don't mind it because my focus on using UnderStrap is the flexibility of coding with JavaScript, BootStrap and custom SASS rules/properties.